# Formulario PHP a base de datos en mysql

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

tengo un pequeño problema con una base de datos... Estoy realizando un formulario para dar de alta los registros pero al momento de dar clic al botón summit me indica que el registro fue dado de alta mas no se registra nada en mi base de datos. La tabla sobre la que trabajo tiene una conexión de tabla federada en mi localhost, no se si eso tenga algo que ver.

Documento de alta .html

```
<body>
  <div id=alta>
  <center><form name='registro' method="POST" action="altas.php">
 <p>Dirección IP:
   <input type="text" name='Direccion ip' onChange="javascript:while("+this.value.charAt(0)==' ')this.value=this.value.substring(1,this.value.len ght);""><br>
 </p>

 <p>Máscara de Subred:
   <input type="text" name='Mascara de subred' onChange="javascript:while("+this.value.charAt(0)==' ')this.value=this.value.substring(1,this.value.len ght);""><br>
 </p>

 <p>Ocupado por:
  <input type="text" name='Ocupado por' onChange="javascript:while("+this.value.charAt(0)==' ')this.value=this.value.substring(1,this.value.len ght);""><br>
 </p>

 <p>Nodo:
  <input type="number" name='Nodo' onChange="javascript:while("+this.value.charAt(0)==' ')this.value=this.value.substring(1,this.value.len ght);""><br>
 </p>

 <p>Switch/Panel: <select type="text" name:"Switch o panel" value="" onChange="javascript:while("+this.value.charAt(0)==' ')this.value=this.value.substring(1,this.value.len ght);"">
<option value="Switch">Switch</option>
<option value="Panel">Panel</option>
</option>

</select>
</p>

<p>Departamento: <select type="number" name:"iddpto" value="" onChange="javascript:while("+this.value.charAt(0)==' ')this.value=this.value.substring(1,this.value.len ght);"">
<option value="1">Administracion y Finanzas</option>
<option value="2">Asuntos Juridicos</option>
<option value="3">Comercial</option>
<option value="4">Ingenieria de Servicio al Cliente</option>
<option value="5">Mantenimiento</option>
<option value="6">Operación</option>
<option value="7">Planeación y Construcción </option>
<option value="8">Recursos Humanos</option>
<option value="9">Superintendencia </option>
<option value="10">Tecnologías de Información y Comunicacione</option>

</select>
</p>

<input type='submit' id='boton' value='Registrar'>
<input type='reset' id='boton' value='Limpiar'>

  </form></center>
  </div>
</body>
```

*En esta parte me marca el error en .php de Undefined Index para los campos de
 Switch o Departamento en el documento de altas.php que mas adelante pongo

Codigo de conexión a bd lo tengo como libreria2.php

```
<?php    
function conectar_bd($query)
{
$DB_SERVER = "miservidor";
$DB_USER = "miusuario";
$DB_DATABASE = "midb";
$DB_TABLE = "mitabla";
$DB_PWD = "micotraseña";

$conn=mysqli_connect($DB_SERVER, $DB_USER,$DB_PWD,$DB_DATABASE);
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n" , mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$query))
   echo mysqli_connect_error();
return $result;
}
?>
```

Codigo de orden de alta en tabla con nombre altas.php

```
<?php

$Direccion_ip=$Direccion_ip;
$Mascara_de_subred=$Mascara_de_subred;
$Ocupado_por=$Ocupado_por;
$Nodo=$Nodo;
$Switch_o_panel=$Switch_o_panel;
$idDpto=$idDpto;


include('libreria2.php');
$insert = "NSERT INTO `dbIPs`.`ips` (`Direccion ip`, `Mascara de subred`, 
`Ocupado por`, `Nodo`, `Switch o panel`, `idDpto`) VALUES ('$Direccion_ip', 
'$Mascara_de_subred', '$Ocupado_por', '$Nodo', '$Switch_o_panel', 
'$idDpto');";
conectar_bd($insert);

 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
 printf("Connect failed: %s\n" , mysqli_connect_error());
 exit();
 }

 else
 { 
 echo "<br>Dirección IP dada de alta corectamente<br>";
 }

 ?>
```

Tipos de datos dentro de mi tabla

```
CREATE TABLE `ips` (
 `Direccion ip` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 `Mascara de subred` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
 `Ocupada por` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
 `Nodo` INT(11) NOT NULL,
 `Switch o panel` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
 `idDpto` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`Direccion ip`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `Direccion ip_UNIQUE` (`Direccion ip` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `Nodo_UNIQUE` (`Nodo` ASC));
```

Answer (score 1):

el problema es que no estas recibiendo los elementos en tu script PHP, ya que en algunas etiquetas estas declarando `name:"iddpto"` y deberías declarar `name="iddpto"`, en segundo lugar no es buena práctica usar nombres de campos con especios `name:"Switch o panel"`, lo ideal sería `name="switch_Panel"` o algo similar, sin espacios.

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, acabo de percatarme de ese detalle y me soluciono el problema... lo que comentas de los espacio también aplica para mi tabla? es decir, en este caso la columna "Switch o panel" en mi tabla es mas conveniente llamarla "switch_panel"?

Comment: Así es, tambien aplica para las tablas.

Comment: Como consejo general, todo lo que no sea para mostrar información al usuario (textos, mensajes, etc...) debería ir en lo que se dice "lenguaje de máquina", que es que las variables, constantes, funciones, etc... Sean nombradas solamente por alphanimericos y _. mi_variable_de_fecha, mi_funcion_especial... Consulta los standares para usar correctamente tanto los guiones bajos como el camelCase (miVariableDeFecha, miFuncionEspecial).

Answer (score 1):

Además de lo que te dice Jhoubert:

- Revisa la sintaxis de las etiquetas
- Convierte a lenguaje máquina ("abc def" por "abc_def")

No veo en ningún momento que iguales las variables a su correspondiente $_POST.
Si tienes el formulario

```
<form name='registro' method="POST" action="altas.php">
    <input type="text" name='direccion_ip'><br>
</form>
```

En tu PHP deberías tener una forma de recibir estos parámetros:

```
$direccion_ip = $_POST['direccion_ip']
```

Me llama la atención la sintaxis

```
<input type="text" name='Mascara de subred' onChange="javascript:while("+this.value.charAt(0)==' ')this.value=this.value.substring(1,this.value.len ght);""><br>
```

En lo referente a onChange. No lo conozco muy bien pero creo que te sobran comillas.

Comment: Gracias por contestar. No se por que no aparece pero si lo tengo acá en mi código... ahora ya resolví el error de Undefined Index, solo que sigue sucediendo que aun al dar click al botón submit no me registra los datos e mi bd, me arroja el mensaje de registro exitoso... pareciera que mi archivo de ordenes .php no esta funcionando ya que hace un rato elimine las tablas para hacer pruebas y aun me aparecia como registro exitoso, cuando supongo que deberia dar un error de que la tabla no se encontraba...